# Selenium- Issue-Clicking on windows pop-ups

Tags: selenium

I am using selenium to record some tests. We have a save to pdf button on our application that  generates the  windows open/ save or in firefox the ok/cancel windows pop up,
The issue is that i can;t get selenium to record  my ok or cancel action since i think it is not a javascript window?

Does anyone know the command to do that?
thanks

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775904/window-dialogs-popup-handling-in-java-or-javascript/5777429#5777429

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it's not possible to interact with such windows at the moment.

A good workaround for saving files dialog is to save the various parameters (local directory, etc) and tell your browser to not prompt for them, so the window won't pop at all.

See http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/Selenium+Core+FAQ#SeleniumCoreFAQ-Whatyoucan%27tdowithSelenium

Comment: so i guess you cant' handle windows events/popups like the alert to save a document where your are asked to open or save for example with Selenium?

Comment: Selenium can handle only JavaScript pop-ups. windows popups can be handled by creating an executable file using AUTOIT Script. Then execute this file through your client code. Refer the link given in comments above. This might help as well http://qtp-help.blogspot.com/2009/07/selenium-handle-dialogs.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate firefox profile(command to open profile manager:-firefox -P) with the settings you want(you can give settings like where to download and save a file of a particular type automatically without prompting) and instruct your server to use that profile using the command : java -jar 'your server ' -firefoxProfileTemplate 'path_for_firefox_profile'