# Is there a way for Selenium to accept a PKI login certificate prompt using IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pki

I'm using `Selenium WebDriver 2`, and I am trying to automate logging into a web application that requires picking a certificate.

Is there a easy way to accept a PKI certificate prompt while logging into a web app in `IE`?

Currently I'm looking at having to use `AutoIt` to accept the certificate, but I want to make sure this is the only option before I pursue this course.

Comment: Just a thought - did you try recording a macro?

Comment: I haven't, I generally don't use the Selenium IDE. But it can't hurt to try it!

Comment: Yeah, that's usually what I (lazily) first try when I can't figure something out or don't know some syntax.

Comment: Good thinking, but no luck with recording the macro. It doesn’t pick up the cert selection clicks.

Comment: Hmm, well some other searching seems to think you can [use `getAlert()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775904/window-dialogs-popup-handling-in-java-or-javascript), but this isn't an alert window. I also [saw the 3 steps linked off of here](http://automationtestingutilities.blogspot.com/p/handling-windows-authentication.html) - looks like someone wrote a small DLL and used it in conjunction with some other tools to actually handle Windows dialogs with Selenium. I haven't tested anything, but good luck if you try them out.

Comment: Great, thank you! I will check out those links and report back on what I find

Comment: Try to use JSOUP  API for secure login. or try using http://username:password@xyz.com

Comment: Good suggestion using JSOUP, however it is how I login to the application under test, and we are testing with Selenium. The link above looks promising but difficult to do if running Selenium on a remote machine. But it is the closest thing I have found yet